# Best way to create a common folder when creating new users that is a drop box, readable and writeable by all users

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, users

What is the best way to provide a common drop box for all users, so that any user that is a part of a particular group can read and write to and from the directory?  I thought of creating a directory outside of the /home directory, creating a group specifically for accessing the directory, then adding all desired users to that group, and finally adding a symlink to the home directory of each user that points to the drop box folder.  That seems like a lot of work.  Is there a better way?

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you want a drop bop for all users, which would imply that all users could write to it, or a drop box that some users can drop into but all users can read from.
Assuming the latter:

1) Create a dir somewhere.

2)  Create a group

3) Add users who you want to have write access to group

4) chgrp

5) chmod g+rws

6) chmod o+rx

The +s in the chmod will set the sticky bit which will cause all files/dirs that are created in  to have the group  and read/write perms for .

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ACLs each user would have specific permissions and you can make custom access to the file and directory.

[man setfacl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl)

---

Another way that comes to my mind is perhaps making a symbolic link of /tmp for your users since it already has the desired permission to acomplish what you want.

---

Your plan sounds ok aswell, example:

1. mkdir /my_shared_folder
2. groupadd my_share_group
3. add users that will have access to the group
4. chmod -R ug+rwx /my_shared_folder
5. chown -R root:my_share_group
6. for f in /home/*; do ln -s /my_shared_folder /home/$f/my_shared_folder; done
7. chmod -R g+s /my_shared_folder (optional, this will allow users to create,delete,modify files/directories)